# How can I automatically forward Wordpress post urls to new structure?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I changed my wordpress file structure a bit. I used to have the wordpress install at the root, but now it is inside a "blog" folder.

So before all the posts had this type of permalink:

> http://www.my-domain-name.com/2015/08/06/post-title-here/

And now it is:

> http://www.my-domain-name.com/blog/2015/08/06/post-title-here/

I'm a bit concerned that users have bookmarked the old url structure other sites are linking to it. Is there any way I can have someone who is visiting the old structure be forwarded to the new structure?

I'm fairly certain I can achieve this using my .htacess folder, but not entirely sure how that is written out. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, you should tell the users to adapt to the new permalink format.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(\d+/\d+/\d+/.*)$ /blog/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

In the above rule, I've put `R=301` so that users will get redirected to new links. If you do not want the new permalink to be shown to user (for whatever reason), just remove the redirection flag.

Comment: Thank you so much! How would you recommend I tell the users to adapt to the new permalink format?

Comment: @zeckdude Put a sitewide notice?

Comment: Like a div with an alert box that says for them to switch out their links? What do you think would be the best way to have the notice only show for people that are trying to access the old permalink format? I was thinking of adding a GET variable at the end of the url they are redirected to and then if that GET variable exists, show the notice. Do you think that is a good solution? I was to do it that way, would this be the correct rewrite rule? RewriteRule ^(\d+/\d+/\d+/.*)$ /blog/$1?old_format [R=301,L,NC]